# PHP convert EPS file to PNG/SVG

Tags: php, svg, imagick, eps, php-7.4

I have an eps file and I want it to convert svg or png format.
I have installed PHP Imagick extension in my localhost and also installed the GhostScript.
I have tried the following code

for eps to svg code

```
$file_path = realpath('./sample.eps');
$dest_path = getcwd() . '/sample.svg';




$command = "inkscape --file=$file_path --export-plain-svg=$dest_path";
$output = shell_exec($command);
var_dump($output);
var_dump(is_file('./sample.svg'));

 

this code return null and bool(false)

 

for eps to png code 
$path = 'http://localhost/Sample.eps';
$save_path = 'http://localhost/imprint_option_2E_c.png';
$image = new Imagick();
$image->setResolution(300,300);
$image->readimage($path);
$image->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
$image->scaleImage(600, 270);
$image->setImageFormat("png");
$image->writeImage($save_path);*/
```

error is : Uncaught ImagickException: Failed to read the file

Comment: For the first *shell_exec()* perhaps `inkscape` isn't in the `path`. You may need to call it with the full path that you could obtain with `which inkscape` in a console.

Comment: For the *Imagick()* solution, the path to the EPS file I wouldn't use an URL but do the same as the first solution with `realpath('sample.eps')`